# Authenticating request to call Wave REST API from @AuraEnabled annotated methods

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to invoke Wave REST API from a @AuraEnabled method. I am using UserInfo.getSessionId() to retrieve current user's session Id and use it as access token to for REST API authentication. But this is the response I receive:

```
{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}
```

Has Salesforce disabled API access a sessions created for lightning app? If yes, what would be the workaround in this case?

Answer (score 2):

From Exploring the [Visualforce App Container Section of the Visualforce & Lightning Experience Trailhead Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_container), here’s something to keep in mind:

> $Api.Session_ID returns different values depending on the domain of the request. This is because the session ID varies during a session whenever you cross a hostname boundary, such as .salesforce.com to .visual.force.com. Normally Salesforce transparently handles session hand-off between domains, but if you’re passing the session ID around yourself, be aware that you might need to re-access $Api.Session_ID from the right domain to ensure a valid session ID.

`UserInfo.getSessionId()` may not at all apply in the context of your `@AuraEnabled method` if called from a lightning component context.